# Mudar atributo de um elemento sem identificação

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível mudar alguns atributos de um elemento sem saber sua identificação?
Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alterar o texto do span para outro qualquer do meu interesse.

Answer (score 6):

Sim, de diversas formas, por exemplo em seu código:

**Utilizando o `find()` do jQuery para encontrar um elemento beaseado em outro:**

```js
$( "#panelFormula" ).find( "span" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelFormula">
 <div class="panel-heading">
<span>Fórmula da Critica</span>
</div>


</div>
```

**Encontrando o elemento com base em seu conteúdo**

```js
$("span:contains(Fórmula da Critica)").css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelFormula">
 <div class="panel-heading">
<span>Fórmula da Critica</span>
</div>


</div>
```

**Em relação a todos os elementos, encontrando o `span` específico que você precisa**

```js
$( "span:nth-child(4)" ).css('background-color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelFormula">
 <div class="panel-heading">
<span></span>  
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span>Fórmula da Critica</span>
</div>


</div>
```

**Do que se trata tudo isso**

Isso se trata de DOM (document object model); é a árvore de elementos que compõem o HTML; as técnicas acima são formas de encontrar com facilidade os elementos que você precisa para realizar suas tratativas, legal?

Esses artigos podem ser úteis também:

- https://www.gigasystems.com.br/artigo/102/filtrando-selecionando-elementos-no-dom-com-jquery
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito.

Answer (score 2):

Baseado no seu código, você pode encontrar o `span` em questão e alterar o texto usando o seletor:

```
$("#panelFormula > .panel-heading span").text("novo texto");
```

Exemplo:

```js
$("#panelFormula > .panel-heading span").text("novo texto");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panelFormula">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <span>Fórmula da Critica</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Não usaria `$( "#panelFormula" ).find( "span" )` porque irá selecionar **todos** os `span` que houver dentro da `div#panelFormula`, e não apenas a que você quer. Isso porque você possui uma `div.panel-body` que poderá ter outros `span`, e o `.find()` irá alterar também o texto desses outros `span` que possam ter.

O seletor `$("#panelFormula > .panel-heading span")` irá pegar o elemento `.panel-heading` filho direto de `#panelFormula` e buscar o `span` dentro dele, que só existe um.

Como elemento com classes podem haver mais de um, é melhor ser mais específico no seletor. Se o elemento `.panel-heading` for único dentro de `#panelFormula`, você pode dispensar o sinal `>`, que significa "filho direto", ficando:

```
$("#panelFormula .panel-heading span").text("novo texto");
```